# Pass value from one page to another with php between

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a simple webpage where the user writes his name and age, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SaveData()
{
// I'm missing this part xD
}
</script>

<input type="text" id="name" value="Enter your name" />
<input type="text" id="age" value="Enter your age" />
<button type="submit" id="btn" onclick="SaveData();
parent.location='http://google.com'">
Click to open Google </button>
```

and I want to write that data on another page calling the php script from javascript function `SaveData()`.
So what am I supposed to change here, and how should the php script look like?

Comment: To achieve this you will need to use AJAX.

Comment: ok, I would like php, but if it's not possible, that AJAX is ok too

Comment: If you just want to pass the data to another page, use HTML forms. Otherwise if you are not very familiar with JS I suggest you take a look at jQuery which have a very simple API for AJAX requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using javascript to redirect the user, why don't you submit the name and age as part of a form to another PHP page like this:

```
<form action="anotherPage.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Enter your name" />
    <input type="text" name="age" value="Enter your age" />
    <button type="submit" id="btn">Click to open Google </button>
</form>
```

And then in anotherPage.php, you could do something like:

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $age = $_GET['age'];

    //save name/age to a database or something

    // redirect user to google
    header('Location: www.google.com');   
?>
```

Comment: so, this will first open the anotherPage.php and then Google?

Comment: The user won't see anotherPage.php (maybe for a second at most) - it will just tell the browser to redirect to Google.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$_SESSION` to pass your data from one page to other. or u can use cookies.

in your code

```
 session_start();

if(isset($_POST['your_input'])){
   $_POST['your_input'] = $_SESSION['your_input'] ;
    }
```

and then you use the variable `SESSION` in your code.
try it your self first.